# How to include single quotes in bash folder expansion?

Tags: bash

**Edited***

I have the following definitions in my bash script:

```
DATE_SUFIX=$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)
NAME="MyBackup_"
FILE_NAME=$NAME$DATE_SUFIX
TMP_DIR="/tmp/"
TMP_BKP=$TMP_DIR$NOME_ARQ"/"
TAR_CMD="tar czPf "
```

and I create a dir list like this:

```
FOLDER_LIST[0]="/opt"
FOLDER_LIST[1]="/etc/apache2/sites-available"
FOLDER_LIST[2]="/home/user"
```

Then I iterate this list with this loop:

```
mkdir $TMP_BKP
for ix in ${!FOLDER_LIST[*]}
do
    CMD=$TAR_CMD$TMP_BKP$(basename ${FOLDER_LIST[$ix]})".tar.gz "${FOLDER_LIST[$ix]}"/* "$EXCLUDE
    echo $CMD
done
```

I also have some code to generate the $EXCLUDE part. I does it the same way. 
But the relevant part of code for this question is that `"${FOLDER_LIST[$ix]}"/*` part in CMD expands to:

```
"/home/user/mybackupfolder/foo /home/user/mybackupfolder/bar ..."
```

the problem is that one of the expanded sub-folders has spaces in it, generating:

```
"/home/user/mybackupfolder/foo /home/user/mybackupfolder/bar /home/user/mybackupfolder/my spaced dir"
```

and that breaks the following operations. How can I make it expand to this? -

```
"'/home/user/mybackupfolder/foo' '/home/user/mybackupfolder/bar' '/home/user/mybackupfolder/my spaced dir'"
```

Comment: How do you get `foo` and `bar` in your list?

Comment: @roaima edited the question

Comment: How does FOLDER_LIST relate to MY_DIR? None of FOLDER_LIST is a folder that contains a space.

Comment: @roaima oh sorry. When I re-read the question I realized some part of what I originaly wrote was missing. Maybe I accidentally delete it when I was editing. It's complete now. :)

Comment: Looking at that code it seems to me that you would benefit from reading [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @roaima reading the pages you and Gordon sent me I was able to do what I wanted thanks. If you want to put it in the form of an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Answer culled from comment thread*)

This seems to be a case where quotes are either missing or wrongly applied. You cannot put quotes into a string and have the shell to interpret the result as a quoted string.

Please could I suggest that you read [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and see if that helps.